# Отличие метода isdigit и isnumeric в Python

Tags: python

Я заметил, что методы isdigit и isnumeric выполняют почти одинаковые действия, но в чем же они отличаются?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891070/whats-the-difference-between-str-isdigit-isnumeric-and-isdecimal-in-python/44891278

Comment: https://coderoad.ru/44891070/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-str-isdigit-isnumeric-%D0%B8-isdecimal-%D0%B2-python